# Using sequence in SQL Loader with direct load mode

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am using sql loader in direct load mode.
I need to use sequence in one of the loaded fields.

Direct load doesn't allow use of Oracle SEQUENCE.nextval entity.

There is an option to use a sequence function SEQUENCE(MAX,1)but the problems with it:

1. as the table gets larger and consumes more time to find the max value
2. It's not possible to set starting value of sequence  (in my case the sequence is shared with other objects this why i wanted to use SEQUENCE.nextval)

What are my options?
Maybe it's possible to define a sort of counter in control file with a starting value, and the increased value will be used for sequence?

**Update**

it's possible to use SEQUENCE(n,1) - where n is the starting number.
But when I call sqlloader multiple times, each time providing a different n, each run takes more time to complete the than the previous run.
I don't understand why!!

Comment: Have you considered loading the data and then update the key with an `update .. set key = seq.nextval` ?

Comment: No, there are billions of rows...

Comment: Can you use an external table instead?

Comment: @Alex, what do you mean external table?

Comment: I mean [external tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm) which let you load a file (stored on the server) and make it look like a table. The data isn't loaded into the DB, it exists in an external file. You could then copy data from that into your real table and apply the sequence as you go.

Comment: I am afraid it's not an option :(

Comment: If the column is a primary key, or at least if there's an index on the column, why does it take a long time to find the max value? Does direct path disable the indexes before finding the max value?